# How to hardcode arbitrary Tick text labels on y axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, label, axis, heatmap

I'm using the highcharts heatmap to display fixed interval data, sometimes with 24, 48 or 96 values in a day.

On the y axis I don't want to display each time depending on the interval, this would clutter the y axis.

How can I hardcode arbitrary labels along the extent of the y axis. I want 24:00 at the top, 00:00 at the bottom, and 06:00, 12:00, 18:00 evenly spaced out in between?

24:00  |

.........  |

.........  |

18:00  |

.........  |

.........  |

12:00  |

.........  |

.........  |

06:00  |

.........  |

.........  |

00:00  |

Comment: Use [`tickPositions`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions) or [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner). Then use [`labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) to render labels in `%H:%M` format.

Comment: Thanks @PawelFus, but can you expand on that? What would the actual function look like to get the six strings above in the positions I want?

Comment: If you could create some live demo with issue (jsfiddle with static data, for example), I can make some example which fixes it.

Comment: Sure @PawelFus, heres the example I've been working of http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap-canvas/

Comment: There you have an example of use for `tickPositions`. If you want different order, just comment out `reversed`. If you are missing `24` label, set `max: 24`. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sey0zgm4/ ;)

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't want to depend on the timestamps coming from the data. I want to hardcode the 5 timestamps above in fixed positions along the y axis

Comment: Okay, so could you post **real** demo? The one you have problems with.

Comment: Sorry my dev is quite complex to post, but the jsfiddle above is analogous. i.e. you try to hardcode labels while ignoring the timestamps

Comment: But above example works fine. At least that's what I can see..

Comment: In the jsfiddle he is parsing the Time integer from the csv data in the html portal. I want to hardcode the times regardless of the csv data

Comment: How about just using categories?

Comment: I thought about that, but with categories you are defining what appears between each tick I think? And the number of ticks will vary based on the interval of incoming data. Or am I wrong? Could I fix the number of ticks to    7 and apply text labels between one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what I've asked for is possible, so I ended up computing a suitable tickInterval elsewhere to pass into the chart